# ¿Como puedo solucionar problemas para importar archivos con sequelize?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sequelize.js

estoy empezando a relizar el backend de un sistema en NodeJS y me tope con un error que me tiene detenido ahi, anteriores veces hice de la misma manera y no se me presento ningun error, pero estuvo indigando me decian que podria ser por la version de sequelize que estoy utilizando, intente realizar alguna de la misma manera que algunos ejemplos de la documentacion y no pude obtener exito alguno. Les paso a mostrar parte del proyecto:

[Este es la documentacion sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html)

> index.js

```js
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const {
  Sequelize
} = require("sequelize");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const config = require("./config");

//middlewares
app.use(morgan("dev"));
//app.use(bodyParser.json());

//||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
//--------------------------------------------------
// Conexión a la negocio de Datos
//--------------------------------------------------
const db = new Sequelize("bd_pedidos", "userPedido", "8353086aslom", {
  host: "localhost",
  port: "3306",
  dialect: "mysql",
  operatorsAliases: 0,
  define: {
    timestamps: 0,
  },
});
//||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
//--------------------------------------------------
// TEST DE CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
//-------------------------------------------

try {
  db.authenticate();
  console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
}

//||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
//--------------------------------------------------
// DEFINICION DE MODELOS
//--------------------------------------------------
const models = {};
//negocio


models['Cliente'] = db.import('./models/cliente.js');


//--------------------------------------------------
// Definición de servicios
//--------------------------------------------------
const services = {};
//NEGOCIO
services["Cliente"] = require("./services/cliente.services")(
  services,
  models,
  Sequelize.Op
);

//--------------------------------------------------
// Definición de Controladores
//--------------------------------------------------
//NEGOCIO
require("./controllers/cliente.controllers")(router, services);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);

// CARGADO DEL ENRUTADOR A LA APP
app.use("/api-rest/v1", router);

// MANEJO DE ERRORES
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  return res.status(400).json({});
});

// RELACIONES
//||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
//--------------------------------------------------
Object.keys(models).forEach((nombre) => {
  if (models[nombre].asociar) {
    models[nombre].asociar(models);
  }
});
//--------------------------------------------------
//||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

//INICIALIZACION DE LA APLICACION
app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(
    `API REST corriendo en el puerto https://localhost:${config.port}`
  );
});
```

> package.json

```
{
"name": "sistema_pedidos",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Este es un sistema para realizar pedidos online para una empresa de salteñas",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "Leandro Escalera - marcelo.escalera.inf@gmail.com",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
    }
}
```

La estructura de mi proyecto es el siguiente:

```
-db
-node_modules
-src
--controllers
--models
--services
--config.js
--index.js
-package.json
-package-lock.json
```

El error que me sale es este:

> models['Cliente'] = db.import('./models/cliente.js');
> TypeError: db.import is not a function

Comment: Pero si en la [documentación](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html) que enlazas dice claramente que el método que intentas usar está obsoleto (*deprecated*). Debes usar `require` para importar tu modelo. Saludos

Comment: intente de la manera que indica la documentacion y pues no resulta de la misma manera me sigue saliendo "models['Cliente'] = db.require('./models/cliente.js');
                       ^

TypeError: db.require is not a function"